# Как правильно выделить элемент из списка?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте. Есть список ресурсов. Хочу удалить определенный ресурс. Но удаляется первый попавшийся.

```
@foreach($catalogs as $catalog)
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ $catalog->id }}</th>
      <td>{{ $catalog->name }}</td>
      <th>{{ $catalog->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</th>
      <td>
      <div class="btn-group btn-group text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm m-r-5" role="button" id="deletebtn" data-url="catalog" data-id="{{ $catalog->id }}" onclick="confirmDelete()"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light btn-sm" role="button"><i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i></a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

// jquery

```
function confirmDelete(id) {
  swal({
    title: "Вы уверины?",
    text: "Вы не сможете восстановить данный ресурс!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: 'Отмена',
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
    confirmButtonText: "Да, удалить!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
  }, function (isConfirm) {
    if (!isConfirm) return;
    var id = $('#deletebtn').data('id');
    var url = $('#deletebtn').data('url');
    $.ajax({
      url:  url + '/' + id,
      type: "delete",
      data: id,
      dataType: "html",
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
      },
      success: function () {
          swal("Готово!", "Ресурс успешно удален!", "success");
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          swal("Ошибка!", "Попробуйте еще раз", "error");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Вот тут и возник вопрос. Как указать, что бы скрипт удалял именно тот элемент, по которому произведен клик?

Comment: Так удаляется не тот ресурс который надо удалить. Если например в таблице 9 ресурсов, я жму на кнопку что бы удалить ресурс с ид 5, но удаляется первый ресурс (самый верхний) с ид 1,а не с ид 5

Comment: Вы создаете html-элементы с повторяющимися `id`. Поэтому и находится всегда первый из них.

Comment: $this есть такое ключевое слово, узнаешь его id и успешно удаяляешь

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle спасибо. Уже нагуглил)

Comment: молодца, ковбой)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение
`onclick="confirmDelete(this)"`

```
function confirmDelete(element) {
  var button = element.id;
}
```